# Clickhouse Batch Execution not inserting new rows

Tags: java, jdbc, clickhouse

I have just installed a clickhouse server locally, with package `clickhouse-server` linux package.
I created some java code to insert N rows in table and it works well via JDBC.
However to improve, performance I am now implementing it using batch instead of separate INSERTS, but the code below is not working and the executeBatch function is returning an array with length 0.

For testing purposes i created the following code:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws PulsarClientException, SQLException {

       Connection con = null;
       String connectionString = "jdbc:clickhouse://localhost:8123/bank";

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
     
        String query = "INSERT INTO bank.test (numero,palavra) VALUES (3,'girassol');";

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        con.setAutoCommit(false);      
        try {
            stmt.addBatch(query);
            stmt.addBatch(query);
            stmt.executeBatch();

            con.commit()
        
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        con.close();

    }
```

The `stmt.executeBatch();` returns 0 elements and nothing is inserted onto the clickhouse server. I tested the same code on a Postgres DB just by replacing the connectionstring and it worked as expected.
Is there any configuration that I am missing on clickhouse?

Comment: everything is wrong here. CH does not support transactions. It's not a batch insert in terms of Clickhouse. Clickhouse does not return a number of inserted rows (it always 0).

Comment: example for CH
https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-jdbc/blob/master/src/test/java/ru/yandex/clickhouse/integration/BatchInsertsTest.java#L168

Comment: Yup turns out all I had to change is use  preparedstatements instead of statemtns just like in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Try preprocessing to insert data:

```
// Setting Preprocessing Strings
String query = "INSERT INTO bank.test (numero,palavra) VALUES (?,?);";
```

then, insert each parameter, and add the parameters to the batch, and submit the parameters:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.preparedStatement(query);
// setting first parameter
stmt.setInt(1, 3);
// setting second parameter
stmt.setString(2, "girassol");
stmt.addBatch();
stmt.executeBatch();

con.commit();
```